# Make div stay in certain position below div that programmatically increases in height

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I currently have some JavaScript code that creates a "typing" effect. Now as this effect comes onto screen, the height of the div that contains this text increases. I also have some buttons below this div. Basically the functionality I'm trying to achieve is so that the buttons remain in place while the div above it increases. The buttons below it would be essentially right below the end position of the typed text. If I set a height for the typed text, then it won't be responsive on different screens. If I set no height, then the buttons below the div begin jumping down the screen as the height of the typed text increases. Here is my code as I have it:

```js
// set up text to print, each item in array is new line
var arrText = new Array(
  "Some typed example text",
  "blah blah blah"
);
var speed = 60; // time delay of print out
var index = 0; // start printing array at this posision
var arrLength = arrText[0].length; // the length of the text array
var scrollAt = 20; // start scrolling up at this many lines

var textPos = 0; // initialise text position
var contents = ""; // initialise contents variable
var row; // initialise current row

function typewriter() {
  contents = " ";
  row = Math.max(0, index - scrollAt);
  var destination = document.getElementById("typedtext");

  while (row < index) {
    contents += arrText[row++] + "<br />";
  }
  destination.innerHTML =
    contents +
    arrText[index].substring(0, textPos) +
    "<span class='blink'>█<span>";
  if (textPos++ == arrLength) {
    textPos = 0;
    index++;
    if (index != arrText.length) {
      arrLength = arrText[index].length;
      setTimeout("typewriter()", 500);
    }
  } else {
    setTimeout("typewriter()", speed);
  }
}

typewriter();
```

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 30px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "buttons";
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 6rem;
}

.header {
  height: fit-content;
}

#typedtext {
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Consolas', monospace;
  font-size: 8rem;
}

.button {
  color: white;
  margin: 1rem 1rem 1rem 0rem;
  padding: 0.3em 0.4em 0.3em 0.4em;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #21262d;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div class="header">
    <div id="typedtext"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <a class="button">Button 1</a>
    <a class="button">Button 2</a>
    <a class="button">Button 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just set `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`, and then place the element where you want it to stay? `.buttons { position: absolute; }`

Comment: @ObsidianAge if I set the position to absolute, wouldn't that make it bug out if the user changes the window size?

Comment: I didn't understand. You said you want your buttons to stay at their position but then also you want them to be under your text while your div height is increasing. Would you explain your goal a little bit more?

Comment: @Pulse Well, you can see in the code snippet, the buttons below the text jump as the text is produced. If I set it to a specific height, then if the user changes the window size, the text will vary in it's position in relation to the buttons. I want the buttons to, no matter the window size, always be right below the text, but without the initial "jumpiness" as the text is being "written" out.